# Exclude invisible Inputs with parsley.js 2.x

Tags: parsley.js

How do I tell the parsley-Instance to exclude not visible form elements?

I found this in the Documentation:

`data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden"`

But I dont now where to set this Option? How can I parse this option to the Constructor?

Further Info: I am binding parsley to my form with `jQuery("#formid").parsley();`

Thanks a lot.
Greets

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either do:

```
jQuery("#formid").parsley({ excluded: "input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden" });
```

Or

```
window.ParsleyConfig = { excluded: "input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden" };
<script src="parsley.js"></script>
```

(see http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-global-configuration)

Comment: sorry it's not working and your current documents shows "data-parsley-excluded" instead "excluded"

Comment: The documentation focuses on configuration using the DOM API included in ParsleyJS, since once of the touted features of ParsleyJS is "validation without a single line of JS code!". Of course, the option to use JS is still there. I wish there was more documentation on using JS with ParsleyJS, perhaps in a different version or section of the documetation.

Comment: Parsley options can be configured as HTML data attributes e.g. data-parsley-excluded or they can be configured using JS e.g excluded. Note the JS version doesn't use "data-parsley-"

Answer (score 1):

To disable globally, I added this to the same js page where I set up custom validators, ie:

```
  window.Parsley.options.excluded = "input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden" ;

  window.Parsley.addValidator('noemoji', {
    requirementType: 'boolean',
    ...
```

Comment: I works with parsley.js v2.9.2!

Answer (score 1):

With parsley.js v2.9.2, I works with two ways,

First, global config, quote from [rossinboulder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62120197/10298544)

```js
window.Parsley.options.excluded = "input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden" ;
```

Second, From document, set on form

```html
<form data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], [disabled], :hidden">
...
</form>
```

I didn't find the way to set in global config from document now, that's really strange...